# How to get current Combo / textbox id (workable on new added elements) from same name elements?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, combobox

I am creating new rows using JavaScript successfully.

> I want to get the 'index' of current 'Combo' on 'change' event for
>   some programming purpose.

But following code just works on first row (available on page-load) and does not work for new added elements. Moreover it just works for text-boxes (input) and not for combos (select). Please help.

Using code for text-boxes (input-tag) - working for 1st row only:

```
var textboxes = $('input[name="quantity[]"]');
textboxes.on('blur', function() {
    var index = textboxes.index( this );
    alert( this.value + ', ' + index );
});
```

Using code for Combos (select-tag) - not working

```
var combos = $('combo[name="item_id[]"]');
combos.on('blur', function() {
    var index = combos.index( this );
    alert( this.value + ', ' + index );
});
```

HTML:

```
<select name="item_id[]" id="item_id[]" class="combo" style="width:326px;" <?php echo empty($_GET['id'])?'':'disabled';?> onchange="showAvailableQty(this.value);">
<?php $item_id=!empty($record['item_id'])?$record['item_id']:-1;echo $item_registration->fillCombo($item_id);?>
</select>
```

**EDIT :**

Actually I want the code to return 'index' of item-combo (having same-names) on change-event not only on the row in the picture (1st-row) below but also for the rows which will be added on clicking 'Add Rows' link.

> If you provide some working code, please make sure that it runs on
>   newly added elements too. Thanks

html code:

```
<select name="item_id[]" id="item_id[]" class="combo" > option-tags </select>
```

[image]

Thanks,

Comment: Can we see the HTML please?

Comment: <select name="item_id[]" id="item_id[]" class="combo" style="width:326px;" <?php echo empty($_GET['id'])?'':'disabled';?> onchange="showAvailableQty(this.value);" >
     <?php
                        $item_id=!empty($record['item_id'])?$record['item_id']:-1;
                        echo $item_registration->fillCombo($item_id);
                    ?>
                </select>

Answer (score 0):

**[Working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/z_acharki/jnwrc5ay/235/)**.

As written now the selector will search for the tag `combo` with name `item_id[]`, you're just missing the dot `.` before the `combo` class in :

```
var combos = $('.combo[name="item_id[]"]');
________________^
```

**NOTE :** You could use the current blured element object `$(this)` to get the `index` and `value`.

And you should use event delegation `on()` if you want to deal with fresh DOM added dynamically to the page

Hope this helps.

```js
$('body').on('blur', 'input[name="quantity[]"]', function() {
  var index = $('input[name="quantity[]"]').index(this);
  var value = $(this).val();

  console.log( value + ' , ' + index );
});

$('body').on('change', '.combo[name="item_id[]"]', function() {
  var index = $('.combo[name="item_id[]"]').index(this);
  var value = $(this).val();

  console.log( value + ' , ' + index );
});

$('body').append('<select name="item_id[]" id="item_id[]" class="combo" style="width:326px;"><option value="i_4">item_4</option><option value="i_4i">item_4i</option><select>');

$('body').append('<br><input name="quantity[]" type="text" value="q_4"/>');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input name='quantity[]' type='text' value="q_1"/>
<input name='quantity[]' type='text' value="q_2"/>
<input name='quantity[]' type='text' value="q_3"/>
<br>
<br>
<select name="item_id[]" id="item_id[]" class="combo" style="width:326px;">
  <option value="i_1">item_1</option>
  <option value="i_1i">item_1i</option>
</select>

<select name="item_id[]" id="item_id[]" class="combo" style="width:326px;">
  <option value="i_2">item_2</option>
  <option value="i_2i">item_2i</option>
</select>

<select name="item_id[]" id="item_id[]" class="combo" style="width:326px;">
  <option value="i_3">item_3</option>
  <option value="i_3i">item_3i</option>
</select>
<br><br>
```

Comment: Thanks, you provided a detailed ans. but in my case it is not working. Actually in a row, I have a select-Combo (item_id-field) and another <span> is to show available Quantity on-change item_id, when an item is selected its Qty (available) should be shown.

Comment: Your code is working well on console but only on the row that was loaded with Page-load. On newly/later added items it has no effect. And it works on console.log but not shows alert() if used. Plz help.

Comment: Please see the answer I have posted to know more detail.

Comment: Check my update @asif, it should work with fresh DOM added by javascript..

Comment: You are working hard for me but sorry to say that still not giving correct index of Item_id[] nor quanity[]. Also better if combo works on-change event. I want "Right index of just item_id[]' combos for dynamically added rows", thanks :-)

Answer (score 0):

Actually I want the code to return 'index' of item-combo (having same-names) on change-event not only on the row in the picture (1st-row) below but also for the rows which will be added on clicking 'Add Rows' link.

> If you provide some working code, please make sure that it runs on
>   newly added elements too. Thanks

html code:

```
<select name="item_id[]" id="item_id[]" class="combo" > option-tags </select>
```

[image]

Comment: I've updated your OP, i'll be better to remove this post now.